# Class-based React Component with Inheritance: "render" is not assignable to the same property in base type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have a new React Native app that uses Typescript. I want to use class based components. At this time, I have two classes:

**RouteView.tsx**

```
 export class RouteView extends React.Component {
    constructor(props: any, private title: string) {
        super(props);

        this.params = params;
        this.title = title;    
    }

    render() {
        return <div></div>;
    }
 }
```

**HomeView.tsx**

```
export class HomeView extends RouteView {
  render() { return 
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>My Mobile App!</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <Button
        title="View About"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('About')}
      />
    </View>;
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
  });
```

When I compile this, I receive an error that says:

*Property 'render' in type 'HomeView' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'RouteView'.*

Why? The code looks correct to me. In `HomeView`, I'm trying to override the `render` method of the base class. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Do not use inheritance in react](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#so-what-about-inheritance). Favour composition. Your life will be much easier.

Comment: Aside from the comment above, it's hard to determine exactly what's wrong because your code isn't formatted properly. Given the current format, it looks like your `HomeView` render method could return `undefined` (which is different than the parent and incompatible with React.Component because render should never return undefined), but it's not possible to tell. Build a [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/) that demonstrates your error and link it here

Comment: I created a [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/77NSF-C8lZaOQZMHJA3Xq). Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### NOTE

***Please*** [don't do inheritance](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#so-what-about-inheritance). There's so much history in React at to why inheritance is the wrong way to solve problems and why composition solves all the problems from the smallest scale to the largest scale applications.

### Immediate Answer

Given your [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/77NSF-C8lZaOQZMHJA3Xq), it just looks like your return statement is returning the JSX. It should look like this:

```
export class HomeView extends RouteView {
  render() { 
    return (
     <View style={styles.container}>
       <Text>My Mobile App!</Text>
       <StatusBar style="auto" />
       <Button
         title="View About"
         onPress={() => navigation.navigate('About')}
       />
     </View>
    )
  }
}
```

[image]